# How to hide specific column in tree view for odoo12?

Tags: view, treeview, odoo, erp, odoo-12

I have one field was the M2o and that opposite O2m. I try to display the O2m field in the M2o class just like that and display all the O2m field in the tree view. But I need to hide the one column is based on the ir.config_parameter

```
 from odoo import models, fields, api
    class AbcXyz(models.Model):
        _name='abc.xyz'

        b_ids=fields.One2many('xyz.abc','a_id',string="Xyz")

       @api.model
       def fields_view_get(self, view_id=None, view_type='form', toolbar=False, submenu=False):
            res = super(AbcXyz, self).fields_view_get(view_id=view_id, view_type=view_type, toolbar=toolbar, submenu=submenu)
            if view_type=='form' and self.b_ids:
                for line in self.b_ids:
                    is_applying_view = eval(self.env['ir.config_parameter'].sudo().get_param('test_module.is_applying_k_qty'))
                    doc = etree.XML(res['arch'])
                    if is_applying_view:
                        for node in doc.xpath("//field[@name='line.k_qty']"):
                            node.set('invisible', '0')
                    else:
                        for node in doc.xpath("//field[@name='line.cartoon_qty']"):
                            node.set('invisible', '1')
            return res

    class XyzAbc(models.Model)
        _name='xyz.abc'

        @api.multi
        def get_default_k_qty_visible(self):
             return eval(self.env['ir.config_parameter'].sudo().get_param('test_module.is_applying_k_qty'))


         a_id=fields.Many2one('abc.xyz',string="ABC")
         <!---other fields--->
         k_qty=fields.Integer(string="Cartoon Qty", default=0)
         is_k_qty_visible = fields.Boolean(string="Is K Qty Visible", compute=get_default_cartoon_qty_visible, store=True)
```

based is_k_qty_visible I try to hide the k_qty column.

```
<record id="abc_form_view" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">abc.form.view</field>
        <field name="model">abc.xyz</field>
        <field name="type">form</field>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <form string="ABC Process">
                <notebook>
                        <page string="K Qty">
                            <field name="b_ids" nolabel='1' mode="tree">
                               <tree>
                                  <field name="k_qty" attrs="{'invisible':[('is_k_qty_visible','!=',True)]}" />
                              </tree>
                            </field>
                        </page>
                </notebook>
            </form>
        </field>
    <record>
```

But it not working for me.

Comment: Yes. Seems your code hide only the value of "K Qty", not entire column "K QTY". You should try with "fields_view_get()" method and restructure tree element with desire columns.

Comment: @BhaveshOdedra no I hide an entire column for "K Qty".

Comment: @BhaveshOdedra but I try to fields_view_get() method for the "AbcXyz" class but it is not called that time.

Answer (score 1):

This is not the answer of this question. I have share some information.

This code is used to hide fields in one2many(tree) in odoo11

**<
field name="my_field" attrs="{'column_invisible': [('parent.field_name','=',False)]}" />**

this type of code only works gives 'parent' in condition

I think this will type of code will work in odoo12 too.